# Strange behavior of Android 9 patch image

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am developing a chat application for that I am using 9 patch bubble

Function for displaying the bubble on screen

```
 static void showMessage(String message, boolean leftSide) 
    {
        Log.d("abc","show");
        final TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setText(message);

        int bgRes = R.drawable.left_message_bg;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



        if (!leftSide) 
        {
            bgRes = R.drawable.right_message_bg;
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;


        }

        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        textView.setBackgroundResource(bgRes);

         messagesContainer.addView(textView);

                // Scroll to bottom
         if (scrollContainer.getChildAt(0) != null) 
                  {

                    scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollContainer.getScrollX(), scrollContainer.getChildAt(0).getHeight());

               }

                scrollContainer.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

            }
```

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:hint="message text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" android:layout_above="@+id/messageEdit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/meLabel" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messagesContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerforchat"
        android:text="Me"
        android:id="@+id/meLabel" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerforchat"
        android:text="Friend"
        android:id="@+id/friendLabel" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:textSize="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But is giving strange behavior when tested on android 2.3.Its looking nice in Samsung Glaxy S3

[image: Glaxy s3 result]

[image]

1st one isGalaxy S3 screenshot.
2nd one Android 2.3 screenshot.Blue bubble is showing weird in android 2.3

```
left_message_bg-->The orange bubble which will display after sending message

right_message_bg-->The blue bubble which will display after receiving message
```

9 patch images

[image]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you've placed the 9-patch in only one drawable folder (`drawable-xhdpi`). When placed on a device that's *not* xhdpi, it gets scaled down (including the defining outer black pixels) and is no longer able to be interpreted as a 9-patch, so it fails. Either make a scaled mdpi and hdpi version, or place it in `drawable-nodpi`.

Comment: I have placed them in all folder with different densities

Comment: Can you post the 9-patch that is having problems, then?

Comment: Hmm, I'm honestly not sure. My one comment would be that you only need one pixel on the top and left, but it won't break to have it the way you have it now. It seems to be a measurement issue. Is there a reason you're not using a ListView and Adapter for this?

Comment: I also tried by interchanging the image means blue bubble for displaying send msg and orange for displaying received msg.Now its showing blue one properly but wired orange bubble.Its only giving problem for displaying received msg

Comment: Hmm there is no genuine reason for not using list view.Will it fix the problem??

Comment: I'd say it probably would, just indirectly. Something else is causing the measurements to be off. Just for laughs, can you try removing the line to `setLayoutParams` on the text view, and change the addView call to `messageContainer.addView(textView, params);`?